# Use a RadioButtonList update list columns?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2007, asp.net, list-form, user-controls

Does anyone know if it's possible using SPD w/ MOSS2007 to use a RadioButtonList value to update columns in a list using a custom insert list form without binding the `asp:RadioButtonList` on page load, I want to use custom values i.e.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="radiolist1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
<asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score -1):

The RadioButtonList control is used to create a group of radio buttons.

RadioButtonList are used when we need to make multiple sets of choices available, but we want the user to select only one of them. If they click on a second selection after making a first, the first selection is removed.

RadioButtonList also supports data binding.

c#

j#

vb

c++

c

For more details please check out this link...

http://mindstick.com/Articles/ba2249fb-7735-44d4-9736-5a84b5570360/?RadioButtonList%20Control%20in%20ASP.Net

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this answer is specific to the question itself but a definition of RadioButtons. Can you explain more on how you would solve this specific question?